# Postgres Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Select"

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

I am receiving the following:

Error in query:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "Select" LINE 4: (Select remoteaddr,
>   count(remoteaddr) remoteaddrCount

```
Select Tim1.remoteaddr,Tim1.remoteaddrCount,  Tim2.domain_id
From domain_visitors

(Select remoteaddr, count(remoteaddr) remoteaddrCount
From domain_visitors
Group by remoteaddr
Having count(remoteaddr)>500) Tim1,

(Select distinct remoteaddr, domain_id
From domain_visitors) Tim2
Where Tim1.remoteaddr=Tim2.remoteaddr
```

Comment: Yes, that is bad syntax alright. If you tell us what you are trying to achieve, maybe someone can help.

Comment: You need to `JOIN` those derived tables somehow. `from domain_visitors JOIN (select ...) as tim1 on tim1.some_col = domain_visitors.some_other_col JOIN (select ... ) tim2 on Tim1.remoteaddr=Tim2.remoteaddr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have exuberancy table name `domain_visitors` after `From` and before the sub query.

Let try again with

```
Select Tim1.remoteaddr,Tim1.remoteaddrCount, Tim2.domain_id From 
(Select remoteaddr, count(remoteaddr) remoteaddrCount From domain_visitors Group by remoteaddr Having count(remoteaddr)>500) Tim1
JOIN 
(Select distinct remoteaddr, domain_id From domain_visitors) Tim2 ON Tim1.remoteaddr=Tim2.remoteaddr
```

Hopefully this answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma between the 1st table in the `FROM` and the expression creating `Tim1`

```
Select Tim1.remoteaddr,Tim1.remoteaddrCount, Tim2.domain_id 
From domain_visitors,  -- <-- MISSING COMMA 
  (Select remoteaddr, count(remoteaddr) remoteaddrCount 
     From domain_visitors 
     Group by remoteaddr 
     Having count(remoteaddr)>500) Tim1,
  (Select distinct remoteaddr, domain_id 
     From domain_visitors) Tim2 
Where Tim1.remoteaddr=Tim2.remoteaddr
```